# Python Connect to Hive on EMR

Tags: python-3.x, hive, amazon-emr

Is there a way to connect to a Hive table on an AWS EMR cluster through Python?

I've been trying several packages like pyhive, ibis, and impyla to name a few, but no luck. I've tried using the exact info as what I use in PuTTy to ssh but still keep getting errors.

In PuTTy:

Host Name: (username)@(Master public DNS of EMR)

Port: 22

Auth: using a .ppk file

[EMR info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puNFA.png)

```
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host = "(Master public DNS of EMR)",
                       port = 22, username = '(username)', database = '(database)')
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
TTransportException: Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'
```

Should I be using the .ppk file as well?

Comment: I don't think that your EMR is accessible on port 22. Try port 10000

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/HiveJDBCDriver.html

Comment: @amf050895 Are you able to solve this issue?